# Compiling part of Typescript project is causing an error

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a Typescript project containing two main folders: `src` & `test`.
When compiling the TS code, I want to compile just the `src` folder. I don't need the tests in the `dist` folder.

So, I set these settings in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
"rootDir": "./src",
"outDir": "./dist",
```

I thought that was the way to do it. But unfortunately, when I run the `tsc` compiler, I get an error message:

```
error TS6059: File '...my-proj/test/test.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '...my-proj/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Matched by default include pattern '**/*'
```

(Another unexpected result is that in addition to compiling the `src/*` files to the `dist` folder, the compiler creates `js` files in the `test` folder, side by side with the original files.)

How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: Have you tried using `include: ["./src/*"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not excluding the tests folder from typescript compilation or you haven't set the directories or files to include.

Either include the files you want to compile or exclude the ones you don't want

This is an example `tsconfig.json` to achieve it.

```
{
   "include": ["src/**/*"],
   "exclude": ["node_modules", "test/**/*"],
}
```